# error [Error] cannot convert 'char**' to 'char*' in assignment

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 4;

int main ()
{

    char *names[MAX] = {
        "Zara Ali",
        "Hina Ali",
        "Nuha Ali",
        "Sara Ali",
    };

    char *ptr[MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
         ptr[i] = &names[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        cout << "Value of names[" << i << "] = ";
        cout << *ptr[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you do to attempt fixing the problem? Besides copy/pasting your code into SO?

Comment: Did you consider checking the line the compiler points at and see if there is anything fishy?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change:

```
ptr[i] = &names[i]; // `&names[i];`is pointer to char*
```

to

```
ptr[i] = names[i];
```

another thing is that you should store literals as `const char*` and not `char*`, so also change:

```
char *ptr[MAX];
char *names[MAX] = {
```

to:

```
const char *ptr[MAX];
const char *names[MAX] = {
```

---

You can read above in your compiler error/warnings, so I suggest you learn how to read them, in this case:

```
prog.cc:23:13: error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'char **'; remove &
     ptr[i] = &names[i];
            ^ ~~~~~~~~~
```

compiler gives you information exactly where assignment is located, also it gives you exact information what to do: `remove &`. This output is from clang which I  think has one of the best error messages.

Answer (score 2):

What Marcin said

```
ptr[i] = names[i];
```

this is because names[i] is actually a pointer. finally in order to print

```
cout << ptr[i] << endl;
```

because ptr[i] is also a pointer